# varies according to the age of each group of students who vs. varies according to the age of each group of students that

Tags: prepositional-phrases, who-whom, that-vs-which

1. *Our approach to teaching varies according to the age of each group of students **who** start with us from the age of four, through primary and secondary school ages.*
2. *Our approach to teaching varies according to the age of each group of students **that** start with us from the age of four, through primary and secondary school ages.*

The first sentence comes from https://tickitenglish.com. The second is just my rewrite of it.

Methinks, the second is correct because *that* refers to *group of students* and not to *students*. That's why I think it should be written with *that* instead of *who*. Am I wrong?

Comment: the "age of each group of students" is a mistake. It's the students' age group. So, for example, one age group can be 10- and 11-year olds. And all that repetition of the word ages is unnecessary.

Comment: The sentence as a whole is badly expressed. It would be better divided into two, the second sentence beginning _Students start with us at the age of four..._

Comment: The students "start with us" is referring to the human members of the age group.  As such, "who" is reflexive of the students who comprise the group.

Comment: If the word "students" was not there, then "that" would refer to the thing "group."  However, in this sentence, "students" is necessary as individuals "who start with us."

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, the sentence is just lengthy and difficult to comprehend.

I'll break down the sentence (specifically your example 1)

Effectively it is:

- [**noun**]: *Our approach to teaching*
- [**verb**] : *varies*
- [**prepositional adverb**]: *according to the age of each group of students who start with us from the age of four, through primary and secondary school ages.*

...where the prepositional adverb built from multiple prepositional phrases:

- [**prepositional phrase 1**]: according to the age
- [**prepositional phrase 2, which modifies PP1**]: of each group
- [**prepositional phrase 3, which modifies PP2**]: of students who
  start with us
- [**prepositional phrase 4, which also modifies PP2**]: from the age
  of four
- [**prepositional phrase 5, which also modifies PP2**] : through
  primary and secondary school ages.

So there are a lot of prepositional phrases which are actually modifying other prepositional phrases. It's just very hard to comprehend.

**HOWEVER, the final answer to your question is that example #2 is correct. Rather, example #1 is incorrect.** I broke down the sentence so that I could show you this:

Looking at PP3, it's obvious that "*who start with us*" acts as an adjective for the "*students*" ... Therefore, the correct wording can't be "who", which is a noun, rather it should be "whom", therefore example #1's sentence structure is incorrect.

Comment: *who* is a pronoun not a noun in #1. *who* may act as a noun but it is not so in this sentence. Would you explain why *whom* instead of *who*? Is it because *whom* is an object pronoun?

Comment: @JohnSmith Sorry, you're technically correct. "Who" is technically a pronoun. I glossed over the fact that pronouns behave similarly to nouns. So, "who" is not the noun *of the sentence*, as in "who" is not the subject. The subject is "approach" ... Still, you are correct that "who" is behaving as an Object of the Preposition "of". So, we should use "whom" instead of "who", since "whom" always acts as the Object of a Preposition. See this link: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/who-vs-whom-its-not-as-complicated-as-you-might-think